# Input string was not in a correct format while doing ParseInt in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to do a Parse int in C# but I am getting the exception in the line `int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C")));` like below

> "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 class Program
   {
    static void Main()
     {
       string fromTo= "M5000C001";
       int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C")));
       int cFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(fromTo.LastIndexOf("C") + 1));
       Console.WriteLine("FromTo" + mFrom);
     }
}
```

Comment: Second param in Substring is a length, not an end index. Hope you can figure out the rest now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`IndexOf` will return the index of the character literal that you have requested.

```
string fromTo= "M5000C001";
int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C") - 1));
int cFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(fromTo.LastIndexOf("C") + 1));
Console.WriteLine("FromTo" + mFrom);
```

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Hi Bala, Thanks a lot, I got the solution.

Comment: @Raj Glad it helped. :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Start by breaking your code apart:

```
string fromTo = "M5000C001";
var stringMFrom = fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C"));
var stringCFrom = fromTo.Substring(fromTo.LastIndexOf("C") + 1);

Console.WriteLine(stringMFrom);
Console.WriteLine(stringCFrom);
```

You'll see from the output that `stringMFrom` contains a character, which is causing the problem.

You can now work out what it is you need to tweak, which looks like it should end up being:

```
string fromTo = "M5000C001";
var stringMFrom = fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C") -1);
var stringCFrom = fromTo.Substring(fromTo.LastIndexOf("C") + 1);

Console.WriteLine(stringMFrom);
Console.WriteLine(stringCFrom);
```

If you now put the calls to `int.Parse` back in, you'll see success:

```
string fromTo = "M5000C001";
var stringMFrom = fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C") -1);
var stringCFrom = fromTo.Substring(fromTo.LastIndexOf("C") + 1);
int mFrom = int.Parse(stringMFrom);
int cFrom = int.Parse(stringCFrom);
Console.WriteLine("FromTo" + mFrom);
```

There's no real need to have the `int.Parse` and `fromTo.Substring` all form part of one statement, it makes it a bit harder to debug in circumstances like this and *it's likely* the compiler will reduce both my code above, and your original (with the added `-1`) to the same code in the end. Always try to write your code so it's as clear and easy to work with as possible *for you*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob I got the solution and Bala gave me example snippet, Anyway thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
  string fromTo= "M5000C001";
       int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C")));
```

In your code `fromTo.Substring(1, fromTo.IndexOf("C"))` would return **5000C**. So do it accordingly either subtract 1 from index  or use lastIndex.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it as you said and bala gave the example snippet to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

another approach using linq (and imho a bit more easy, if you are interrested)

you could split for `M` and `C`, parse them and take first and last. If there is no `C` `Last()` would be equal to `First()`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fromTo = "M5000C001";

    IEnumerable<int> values = fromTo.Split('M', 'C')
                                    .Where(w => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w))
                                    .Select(int.Parse)
                                    .ToList();
    int from = values.First();
    int last = values.Last();

    Console.WriteLine("From" + from);
    Console.WriteLine("Last" + last);
}
```

Comment: This I will try, Seems like shortest form of the program.

Comment: @Raj yep. I really hate messing around with `Substring` and `IndexOf`. I'm happy there often is a `Linq`-way to solve problems.